# Parsing a Lucene query correctly

Tags: lucene

I have the fields "title" and "keyword" in my Lucene (3.6) documents. When I have an object with `title=Testfair 2012-09` and a keyword of `someTest`, I write the document like:

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new Field("title", title, Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
doc.add(new Field("keyword", keyword, Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
```

For searching I use

```
QueryParser queryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36, new String[] { "title", "keyword" }, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36));
queryParser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.AND_OPERATOR);
queryParser.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);
Query query = queryParser.parse(queryString);

IndexSearcher searcher = createSearcher();
TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(1000, true);
searcher.search(query, collector);
ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
```

In the index, I can see (via [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/)) that the field `title` in the index has the values `"Testfair", "2012"` and `"09"`.

Now I'd like the following behaviour when searching:

```
Testfair 2012-09 -> match     (1)
estfair          -> match     (2)
Testfair baz     -> no match  (3)
```

I am not sure how to handle this because I need the implicit wildcard search for case (2). If I split the search term at whitespaces and add `*` before and after every word, I get the search for `+(title:*testmesse*) +(title:*2012-09*)`, so the `2012-09` is not split and no result is found. If I understand correctly the problem lies within the usage of the `MultiFieldQueryParser` but I don't know how I would set up the search correctly or if I should somehow modify the indexing process.

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime, I got the book "Lucene in Action" and took the advice from there: Create a "catch all" field which contains all searchable fields within one field and search that field only. With the help of this trick I can skip the `MultiFieldQueryParser` because I only have one field to search in. Now I can simply analyze the search term and modify it the way I need it.